# How to make excel file on read only mode using itextsharp in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to export excel file in readonly mode, no one can copy the cells data neither edit.

My code is:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";   
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MorotoriamReportData.xls");   
     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     HtmlTextWriter htmlwr = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

     Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
     gvViewLedger.AllowPaging = false; 
     gvViewLedger.RenderControl(htmlwr);

     string headerTable = @"<Table><tr><td>Report Header</td></tr><tr><td>a</td></tr></Table>";

     Response.Write(headerTable);
     Response.Write(sw.ToString());
     Response.End();

     btnExport.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you try to run this function?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the HttpResponse object. You may want to look into using something like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki)